# Margin 0 Auto block works with 50% but not with 100%

Tags: html, css

It's not centering an `<h2>` element with width 100% of the containing div. At 50% it centers just fine, but at 100% it hugs the left edge.

Display properties aren't defined in the immediate parent div. It's defined in the parent of the parent, but changing it to block doesn't seem to change anything. Is there a reason I can't use width 100% with this technique?

## Edit

```
main id="grid">
<section id="main_background_container">
    <img id="main_side_img" src="images/background-1c.png"><img>
    <div id="main_primary_container">
        <div id="main_heading_container">
            <h1 id="main_heading" >INTENSIVAO</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="main_subheading_container">    
            <h2 id="main_subheading">DE INGLES</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="info_primary_container">
            <div id="info_container">
                <div id="info_text_container">
                    <h1 id="info_text_place" class="penis_breath">Paulista</h1>
                    <h2 id="info_text_day" class="penis_breath">Sabados</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="info_time_container">
                    <p class="info_text_time" id="info_text_time_1">8h00 - 11h00</p><br>
                    <p class="info_text_time" id="info_text_time_2">12h00 - 15h00</p>
                </div>
                <div id="info_startday_container">
                    <h2 id="info_text_startday_explain">turmas começam</h2>
                    <h1 id="info_text_startday" class="penis_breath">10 de Maio</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="info_box_1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#main_primary_container{
width: 40%
background-image: url('../images/background-2b.png');
background-position: top;
background-size: cover;
height: 65%;
}
#info_primary_container{
float: left;
display: inline-block;
position:relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#info_text_container{
z-index: 2;
position: realtive;
width: 100%;
}

#info_startday_container{
width: 100%;
;
}
#info_text_startday_explain{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: $binaryColor0;
}
```

Comment: please share the html and css you have written for this

Comment: You got example code to test against?

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/hzGWk/ ?

Comment: `text-align: center` could help you :)

Comment: it could, you're right. I did that with the others. I just would prefer using block for this particular element, rather than inline-block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`margin: 0 atuo` only works with elements that aren't 100% width... The `auto` part sets the left and right margins to `auto`, which gives you the centering effect. If the width is 100%, a margin of `auto` won't do anything.

You can just use `text-align: center` if you want to center an `h2` element.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a rational explanation for why margin auto won't do anything if the width is set to 100%, as opposed to 99%?

Comment: @AndÚ Because a 100% width element doesn't have any play on either side. If you set the margin to like `50px` (some specific value), then it will shrink the element, but `auto` looks for whatever margin is available on either side. A small element has plenty of margin available on each side. Also, if this answer was helpful, please mark as accepted.

Comment: ok, margin: auto won't work with an element set to 100% because there is no space remaining to create a margin. right?